# Get the cosine value of a angle between two lines?

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]

I want to find the cosine value of the Q angle

Comment: Where are you having problem ?

Comment: I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$cos(\theta) = \frac{a \cdot b}{|a||b|}$$

$a = (x_1-x_3)i+(y_1-y_3)j$

$b = (x_2-x_3)i+(y_2-y_3)j$

Comment: what is mean by i and j ?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not related to vectors, a way of solving this problem is to use the *Law of Cosines* (as mentioned in previous posts), which states that, in a triangle with sides *a, b, c* :

$\ c^2 = a^2 - b^2 - 2ab\cos(C) $

where *C* is the angle of the triangle opposite side *c*.

In the diagram above, construct a third segment from *(x1, y1)* to *(x2, y2)*.

Then, calculate the lengths of each of the sides of the resulting triangle using the [distance formula for two points on a Cartesian plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points) This formula is derived from the Pythagorean theorem.

After you have calculated the respective lengths of each side of the triangle, then use the *Law of Cosines* relationship to solve for the cosine of the angle Q.

(Note: relabel angle *Q* as angle *C* and define the segment we have constructed opposite angle *Q* to be side *c*, and proceed from there)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $A = (x_1, y_1)$, and $B = (x_2, y_2)$, and $C = (x_3, y_3)$. Use Pythagorean theorem to find $AB$, $BC$, and $CA$. Then use law of cosine in a triangle to find $\cos C$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula for dot product:
$$
u \dot v = \|u\| \|v\| \cos{\theta}
$$
where $\theta$ is angle between vectors $u$ and $v$.

By picking $u =(x_2-x_3,y_2-x_3)$, $v = (x_1-x_3,y_1-x_3)$. You get cosine of that angle with:
$$
\cos{Q} = \frac{ u \dot v}{\|u\| \|v\|}
$$

Comment: what is mean by v˙ and ∥u∥ ?

Comment: It is norm of $u$. $\|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.